# Windows Server 2008 Network User Shares

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, network-share

What would be the most efficient way to create a different shared folder for each user (not necessarily with desktop, my documents etc inside just a space that can be mapped to his computer), having a windows 2008 server with 30-40 windows 7 client machines on the same network? Would it be using active directory?
Notes: the users dont have accounts on the server machine yet
Thanks!

Comment: `Per user shares` as in home directories for the users?  Clarify your question.

Comment: different shared folder for each user (not necessarily with desktop, my documents etc inside just a space that can be mapped to his computer),

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your latest comment, there are multiple ways to do this and it doesn't require "desktop redirection".

Simple setup included...

You can:

1. Create a share called `\\server\Users` and set the share permissions to `Everyone - Modify/RW` and `Domain Admins - Full Control`.  Then in the NTFS permissions of "USERS" make sure `Domain Admins` has full control and normal `Domain Users` only have `Special` rights for `This Folder Only` of the following:

[image]

Then at that point you have the base share setup.

From here you can:

1. Much to the chagrin of MDMarra, you could use the Profile tab in the user account in AD and set a Home directory drive mapping to `\\server\Users\%username%` and hit apply/OK.  This will auto create a folder in that directory and give the user and that user only full control (besides domain admins).
2. ## 1 above isn't really recommended due to issues.  See Doug's full walkthrough here, but you'll need to setup each user folder manually with permissions: http://blog.luxem.org/2010/07/how-to-setup-home-directories-on.html
3. You can use The Drive Maps extension in GPP now -  `User Configuration > Preferences > Windows Settings > Drive Maps` and map a drive to `\\server\Users\%username%` but you'd need to either have redirection already in place or you'll need to setup the user's folder and their rights to it ahead of time (whereas in step 1 it is done for you)

You can reference:

Doug's excellent article: http://blog.luxem.org/2010/07/how-to-setup-home-directories-on.html
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731729.aspx

Answer (score -2):

Active Directory is the best choice. Create User Groups, then Users, and you can do a clean share of your network resources (disks, printers, internet access...).